# Is there a list of words that will enable the second player in two-player Ghost to always win?

Tags: wordplay

I read in an old puzzle book of mine (I don't remember what it was called, but it had an orange hardback cover and featured only original puzzles) that it is possible to create a list of words that would ensure the second player victory in two person Ghost (a classic word game) every time. For example, starting with C would result in CWM, resulting in victory for the second player. Starting with B would result in BWANA.

Assuming that a three-letter word or longer gets one out, and using the newest official word list from Scrabble as the word source (that's like the OSPD but includes censored words), is this indeed possible, and what are the words?

(For bonus points give me a list assuming four-or-longer as well.)

Comment: Can someone who is familiar with Ruby run this script: https://github.com/hickford/ghost on the OWL4 wordlist?

Comment: I am offering a bounty to whoever posts the answer with based on the OWL 4 wordlist.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: @Rubio, not yet. I did indicate in a number of places why the solution is inadequate - it has not yet been answered with the required word list (The OWL 4, or the Scrabble wordlist.)

Answer (score 6):

It

> isn’t possible for player 2 to always win (or even for one player to always win) as shown by Randall Munroe’s [XKCD blog](https://blog.xkcd.com/2007/12/31/ghost/). If I understand your question correctly, player 1 beginning with H, J, M, or Z will win Player 1 the game every time; player 2 will win the game every other time. Sample lists are found for each letter in the link above.

Comment: "(I hear if you use the Scrabble wordlist, it’s always a win for the second player)."
That is what I'm referring to.

Comment: I don’t get your question, @TheAsh. One of the words in the link is hazard. I’m pretty sure that’s in the Scrabble word list and a win for player 1.....

Comment: no that's not true. HMM is in the Scrabble word list, allowing the second player to win with H by replying with 'M'. Your link does give me enough info to try to solve it for the Scrabble wordlist though.

Comment: MMM is good as well, allowing a winning response for M.

Comment: ZZZ is good too, so Z is a response to Z, allowing the second player to win. J is the only letter that needs further thought

Comment: @TheAsh However, "Hm" and "Mm" are *also* in the Scrabble word list, so replying to "H" or "M" with "M" means you immediately lose.

Comment: @TheAsh:  I think J is a losing strategy as well;  the second player can respond with U, forcing the first player to complete JUS.

Comment: @Chronocidal Did you even bother to read my question? I clearly state a minimum length of three letters. We clearly do not play with two letter words, otherwise the game remains unplayable. In fact many play with a minimum of four or five, hence my bonus question

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: with JU the first player could play N, leading towards June or Juniper... that said, juniper could be a forced win too...

Comment: @El-Guest:  Good point.  I should modify my statement:  the strategy outlined by Randall Munroe no longer works, since JUS is a word in the Scrabble dictionary but is (presumably) not in the Ubuntu wordlist.  I suppose it's possible that there are words in the Ubuntu list that aren't in the Scrabble list as well, meaning that there could be a strategy based on a different chain of responses after the letters JU.

Comment: That was Ash’s quibble with my answer above, @MichaelSeifert.

Answer (score 5):

The book is [David Silverman's *Your Move*.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8tYNQcRov1cC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&source=bl&ots=EHFJgTfU_w&sig=ACfU3U0p1UgMEbQiQs2XPH_PfnOQHv8wMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK1vGFtdjjAhUWRBUIHcYdD_QQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&f=false)

Another easy 2nd-player win the author mentions is DV forcing the first player into DVANDVA or DVORNIK.

Comment: This is great, but not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Curiously enough, I wrote a program to do just this nearly 10 years ago!  I've long since lost the program, but here are all the ways the second player can force a win:

```
a: ['aorta', 'aortographies', 'aortography']
b: ['bwana']
c: ['cnidarian', 'ctenidium', 'ctenoid', 'ctenophoran']
d: ['dwarf', 'dwarves', 'dweeb', 'dwell', 'dwelt', 'dwindle', 'dwindling', 'dwine', 'dwining']
e: ['ejaculate', 'ejaculating', 'ejaculation', 'eject', 'equable', 'equably', 'equal', 'equator', 'equerries', 'equerry', 'equiangular', 'equicaloric', 'equid', 'equilateral', 'equilibrant', 'equilibrate', 'equilibrating', 'equilibration', 'equilibrist', 'equilibrium', 'equimolar', 'equinoctial', 'equinox', 'equip', 'equisetum', 'equitable', 'equitably', 'equites', 'equivalence', 'equivalencies', 'equivalency', 'equivocal', 'equivocator', 'equivoque']
f: ['fjeld', 'fjord']
g: ['gjetost']
h: ['hryvnia']
i: ['ihram', 'ipomoea', 'ipsilateral', 'ivied', 'ivies', 'ivories', 'ivory', 'ivylike']
j: ['jnana']
k: ['klatsch', 'klavern', 'kleagle', 'kleptomania', 'klezmer', 'klezmorim', 'klister', 'klong', 'kloof', 'kluge', 'klutz', 'kwashiorkor']
l: ['llama', 'llano']
m: ['mbira', 'mpret']
n: ['ngwee', 'nyala', 'nylghai', 'nylghau', 'nylon', 'nymph', 'nystagmic', 'nystagmus']
o:  ['oecumenical', 'oedipal', 'oenomel', 'oenophile', 'oersted', 'oesophagi', 'oestrin', 'oestrum', 'oestrus', 'oquassa', 'ozocerite', 'ozokerite', 'ozonate', 'ozonating', 'ozonation', 'ozone', 'ozonide', 'ozonise', 'ozonising', 'ozonization', 'ozonize', 'ozonizing', 'ozonosphere', 'ozonous']
p: ['pneumococci', 'pneumograph', 'pneumonectomies', 'pneumonectomy', 'pneumonia', 'pneumonic', 'pneumonitides', 'pneumonitis', 'ptarmigan', 'pteridine', 'pteridologies', 'pteridologist', 'pteridology', 'pterodactyl', 'pterosaur', 'pterygium', 'pterygoid', 'pteryla', 'ptomain', 'ptyalin']
q: ['quaff', 'quahaug', 'quake', 'quakier', 'quakily', 'quaking', 'quaky', 'quale', 'qualifiable', 'qualification', 'qualified', 'qualifier', 'qualifies', 'qualify', 'qualitative', 'qualities', 'quality', 'qualm', 'quamash', 'quant', 'quare', 'quark', 'quarrel', 'quart', 'quash', 'quasi', 'quass', 'quate', 'quattuordecillion', 'quean', 'queasiest', 'queaziest', 'quebracho', 'queen', 'queer', 'quell', 'quercetin', 'querida', 'queried', 'querier', 'queries', 'querist', 'quern', 'querulous', 'query', 'quest', 'quetzal', 'queue', 'queuing', 'quibble', 'quibbling', 'quick', 'quiescent', 'quiet', 'quiff', 'quill', 'quilt', 'quire', 'quiring', 'quirk', 'quirt', 'quixote', 'quixotism', 'quoin', 'quoit', 'quomodo', 'quondam', 'quota', 'quote', 'quoth', 'quotidian', 'quoting', 'qursh']
r: ['reaccession', 'reacclimatize', 'reacclimatizing', 'reach', 'reacquire', 'reacquiring', 'reacquisition', 'react', 'reaffix', 'reagent', 'reaggregate', 'reaggregating', 'reaggregation', 'reanalyze', 'reanalyzing', 'reanimate', 'reanimating', 'reanimation', 'reannex', 'reassurance', 'reata', 'reattempt', 'reattribute', 'reattributing', 'reattribution', 'reauthorization', 'reauthorize', 'reauthorizing', 'reavail', 'reave', 'reaving', 'reawake', 'reawaking', 'reawoke', 'rebalance', 'rebalancing', 'rebaptism', 'rebaptize', 'rebaptizing', 'rebar', 'rebbe', 'rebec', 'rebegan', 'rebegin', 'rebegun', 'rebel', 'rebid', 'rebirth', 'reblend', 'rebloom', 'reboant', 'reboard', 'rebop', 'rebound', 'rebreed', 'rebroadcast', 'rebuild', 'rebuilt', 'rebus', 'rebut', 'rebuy', 'recalcitrance', 'recalcitrancies', 'recalcitrancy', 'recalculate', 'recalculating', 'recalculation', 'recalibrate', 'recalibrating', 'recalibration', 'recap', 'recarried', 'recarries', 'recarry', 'recce', 'receipt', 'receive', 'receiving', 'recencies', 'recency', 'recension', 'recertification', 'recertified', 'recertifies', 'recertify', 'rechallenge', 'rechallenging', 'rechannel', 'rechart', 'rechauffe', 'recheat', 'recheck', 'recherche', 'rechoreograph', 'rechose', 'rechromatograph', 'recipient', 'reciprocate', 'reciprocating', 'reciprocation', 'reciprocative', 'reciprocities', 'reciprocity', 'recirculate', 'recirculating', 'recirculation', 'recital', 'reclaim', 'reclamation', 'reclame', 'reclasp', 'reclean', 'recline', 'reclining', 'recluse', 'reclusion', 'reclusive', 'recognise', 'recognising', 'recognition', 'recognizabilities', 'recognizability', 'recognize', 'recognizing', 'recollect', 'recolor', 'recommend', 'recompilation', 'recompile', 'recompiling', 'recompose', 'recomposing', 'recomposition', 'recomputation', 'recompute', 'recomputing', 'recon', 'recount', 'recover', 'recrate', 'recrating', 'recriminate', 'recriminating', 'recrimination', 'recriminative', 'recriminatory', 'recross', 'recrown', 'recruit', 'recrystallization', 'recrystallize', 'recrystallizing', 'recta', 'recti', 'recto', 'rectrices', 'rectrix', 'recultivate', 'recultivating', 'recumbent', 'recur', 'recusal', 'recusancies', 'recusancy', 'recut', 'recycle', 'recycling', 'redan', 'redbait', 'redbird', 'redbone', 'redbreast', 'redcoat', 'redfish', 'redhead', 'redia', 'redid', 'redip', 'rediscuss', 'redisplay', 'redispose', 'redisposing', 'redisposition', 'redistill', 'redivivus', 'redline', 'redlining', 'redly', 'redneck', 'redness', 'redpoll', 'redraft', 'redream', 'redress', 'redried', 'redries', 'redrill', 'redrive', 'redriving', 'redroot', 'redrove', 'redry', 'redtail', 'redub', 'reducible', 'reducibly', 'reductant', 'reductase', 'reduction', 'reductive', 'redundant', 'reduplicate', 'reduplicating', 'reduplication', 'reduplicative', 'redux', 'redware', 'redwing', 'redwood', 'redye', 'reechiest', 'reeject', 'reembroider', 'reemphasize', 'reemphasizing', 'reenact', 'reencounter', 'reendow', 'reenforce', 'reenforcing', 'reengrave', 'reengraving', 'reenjoy', 'reenter', 'reentrant', 'reentries', 'reentry', 'reequip', 'reerect', 'reeve', 'reeving', 'reevoke', 'reevoking', 'reexamination', 'reexamine', 'reexamining', 'reexpel', 'reexplore', 'reexploring', 'reexpress', 'refashion', 'refed', 'refel', 'refence', 'refencing', 'refer', 'reffing', 'refight', 'refinance', 'refinancing', 'refit', 'refix', 'reflate', 'reflating', 'reflation', 'reflect', 'reflies', 'refloat', 'reflood', 'refluence', 'refly', 'refocus', 'reforge', 'reforging', 'refortification', 'refortified', 'refortifies', 'refortify', 'refound', 'refract', 'refrain', 'reframe', 'reframing', 'refrangible', 'refresh', 'refried', 'refries', 'refrigerant', 'refrigerate', 'refrigerating', 'refrigeration', 'refront', 'refroze', 'refry', 'refugia', 'refulgent', 'refurbish', 'refurnish', 'refusal', 'refutable', 'refutably', 'refutal', 'regal', 'regatta', 'regauge', 'regauging', 'regencies', 'regency', 'regenerable', 'regenerator', 'reges', 'regicidal', 'regisseur', 'registrable', 'registrar', 'reglaze', 'reglazing', 'regloss', 'regma', 'regna', 'regorge', 'regorging', 'regosol', 'regrade', 'regrading', 'regraft', 'regrant', 'regrate', 'regrating', 'regreen', 'regreet', 'regress', 'regrind', 'regroom', 'regroup', 'regular', 'regulator', 'regulus', 'regurgitate', 'regurgitating', 'regurgitation', 'rehab', 'rehem', 'rehinge', 'rehinging', 'rehospitalization', 'rehospitalize', 'rehospitalizing', 'rehouse', 'rehousing', 'rehydrate', 'rehydrating', 'rehydration', 'rehypnotize', 'rehypnotizing', 'reign', 'reimage', 'reimagine', 'reimaging', 'reimagining', 'reimburse', 'reimbursing', 'reimmerse', 'reimmersing', 'reimplant', 'reitbok', 'reiterate', 'reiterating', 'reiteration', 'reiterative', 'reive', 'reiving', 'rejoice', 'rejoicing', 'rejudge', 'rejudging', 'rejuvenator', 'rejuvenescent', 'rekey', 'relabel', 'relacquer', 'relandscape', 'relandscaping', 'relapse', 'relapsing', 'relatable', 'relator', 'relax', 'relay', 'relearn', 'release', 'releasing', 'relet', 'relevance', 'relevancies', 'relevancy', 'reliabilities', 'reliability', 'reliant', 'relic', 'relieve', 'relieving', 'relievo', 'relight', 'religiose', 'religiosities', 'religiosity', 'religious', 'reliquaries', 'reliquary', 'relique', 'reliquiae', 'relit', 'relocatable', 'relubricate', 'relubricating', 'relubrication', 'reman', 'remap', 'remarried', 'remarries', 'remarry', 'rematch', 'remeasure', 'remeasuring', 'remediabilities', 'remediability', 'remediate', 'remediating', 'remediation', 'remembrance', 'remerge', 'remerging', 'remet', 'remex', 'remiges', 'remigration', 'reminisce', 'reminiscing', 'remit', 'remix', 'remnant', 'remodel', 'remoisten', 'remonstrant', 'remonstrate', 'remonstrating', 'remonstration', 'remonstrative', 'remorid', 'remorse', 'remount', 'removable', 'removably', 'removal', 'remunerator', 'remythologize', 'remythologizing', 'renaissance', 'renal', 'renascent', 'renationalization', 'renationalize', 'renationalizing', 'rencontre', 'renegotiate', 'renegotiating', 'renegotiation', 'renew', 'renig', 'renin', 'renitencies', 'renitency', 'rennase', 'renographic', 'renormalization', 'renormalize', 'renormalizing', 'renovator', 'reobserve', 'reobserving', 'reoccur', 'reoffer', 'reoil', 'reoperate', 'reoperating', 'reoperation', 'reorchestrate', 'reorchestrating', 'reorchestration', 'reorder', 'reoxidation', 'reoxidize', 'reoxidizing', 'repaint', 'repanel', 'repaper', 'reparable', 'repartition', 'repatch', 'repattern', 'repay', 'repechage', 'repeg', 'repel', 'repertories', 'repertory', 'repetitious', 'repin', 'replace', 'replacing', 'replaster', 'replate', 'replating', 'replead', 'replenish', 'replete', 'repletion', 'repleviable', 'replevied', 'replevies', 'replevy', 'replica', 'replied', 'replier', 'replies', 'replumb', 'reply', 'reprehend', 'reprehensible', 'reprehensibly', 'represent', 'repress', 'reprice', 'repricing', 'reprieval', 'reprimand', 'reprint', 'reprise', 'reprising', 'reprivatization', 'reprivatize', 'reprivatizing', 'repro', 'reptant', 'reptile', 'reptilium', 'republish', 'repudiate', 'repudiating', 'repudiation', 'repulse', 'repulsing', 'repulsion', 'repulsive', 'repunctuation', 'reputable', 'reputably', 'requalification', 'requalified', 'requalifies', 'requalify', 'request', 'requiem', 'require', 'requiring', 'requisite', 'requisition', 'requite', 'requiting', 'reradiate', 'reradiating', 'reradiation', 'reraise', 'reraising', 'reran', 'reredos', 'rerelease', 'rereleasing', 'reremouse', 'rerig', 'reroute', 'rerouting', 'rerun', 'resalable', 'resaw', 'resay', 'rescale', 'rescaling', 'rescind', 'rescore', 'rescoring', 'rescuable', 'resee', 'resegregate', 'resegregating', 'resegregation', 'reseize', 'reseizing', 'resemblance', 'resensitize', 'resensitizing', 'reserpine', 'reservation', 'reserve', 'reservice', 'reservicing', 'reserving', 'reservist', 'reservoir', 'reset', 'resew', 'resid', 'resight', 'resilient', 'resin', 'resitting', 'reslate', 'reslating', 'resmelt', 'resocialization', 'resocialize', 'resocializing', 'resod', 'resojet', 'resoluble', 'resolve', 'resolving', 'resonance', 'resonator', 'resound', 'resow', 'respace', 'respacing', 'respade', 'respading', 'respeak', 'respect', 'respell', 'respelt', 'respiration', 'respire', 'respiring', 'respirometric', 'respite', 'respiting', 'resplendent', 'resplit', 'respoke', 'respond', 'responsible', 'responsibly', 'responsions', 'responsum', 'respray', 'resurface', 'resurfacing', 'resurge', 'resurging', 'resurrect', 'resuscitate', 'resuscitating', 'resuscitation', 'resuscitative', 'resyntheses', 'resynthesis', 'resystematize', 'resystematizing', 'retable', 'retag', 'retaliate', 'retaliating', 'retaliation', 'retaliative', 'retaliatory', 'retaste', 'retasting', 'retax', 'retch', 'rethink', 'rethought', 'retia', 'reticence', 'reticencies', 'reticency', 'reticle', 'reticuloendothelial', 'reticulum', 'retie', 'retighten', 'retinitides', 'retinitis', 'retinol', 'retinopathies', 'retinopathy', 'retinoscopies', 'retinoscopy', 'retinue', 'retitle', 'retitling', 'retouch', 'retrace', 'retracing', 'retrack', 'retract', 'retrain', 'retransform', 'retranslate', 'retranslating', 'retranslation', 'retread', 'retreat', 'retrial', 'retribution', 'retributive', 'retributory', 'retried', 'retries', 'retrievable', 'retrieval', 'retro', 'retry', 'retting', 'retwist', 'retying', 'reunification', 'reunified', 'reunifies', 'reunify', 'reunion', 'reunite', 'reuniting', 'reupholster', 'reusabilities', 'reusability', 'reuse', 'reusing', 'reutilization', 'reutilize', 'reutilizing', 'reutter', 'revaccinate', 'revaccinating', 'revaccination', 'revaluate', 'revaluating', 'revaluation', 'revalue', 'revaluing', 'revascularization', 'revel', 'revenge', 'revenging', 'revenue', 'reverie', 'revet', 'revictual', 'revisable', 'revisal', 'revisit', 'revisor', 'revisualization', 'revivable', 'revival', 'reviviscent', 'revocable', 'revoice', 'revoicing', 'revokable', 'revolve', 'revolving', 'revue', 'revuist', 'revulsion', 'revulsive', 'revving', 'rewan', 'rewax', 'reweave', 'reweaving', 'rewed', 'reweigh', 'rewet', 'rewiden', 'rewin', 'rewon', 'rewound', 'rewrite', 'rewriting', 'rewritten', 'rewrote', 'rewrought', 'rexes', 'reynard', 'rhabdocoele', 'rhabdom', 'rhabdovirus', 'rhachides', 'rhachis', 'rhadamanthine', 'rhamnus', 'rhaphae', 'rhapsodic', 'rhatanies', 'rhatany', 'rhenium', 'rheological', 'rheometer', 'rheum', 'rhinencephala', 'rhino', 'rhizobium', 'rhizoctonia', 'rhizoid', 'rhizoma', 'rhizome', 'rhizopi', 'rhizosphere', 'rhizotomies', 'rhizotomy', 'rhodium', 'rhodochrosite', 'rhodolite', 'rhodonite', 'rhodopsin', 'rhodora', 'rhomb', 'rhonchi', 'rhubarb', 'rhumb', 'rhyme', 'rhyming', 'rhyolitic', 'rhyta', 'rhytidome']
s: ['sferics', 'sforzandi', 'sforzando', 'sfumato', 'sgraffiti', 'sgraffito', 'sjambok', 'squab', 'squad', 'squalid', 'squalor', 'squamosal', 'squat', 'squaw', 'squeamish', 'squeezabilities', 'squeezability', 'squeeze', 'squeezing', 'squeg', 'squelch', 'squib', 'squid', 'squiffier', 'squiffy', 'squiggliest', 'squinch', 'squinnied', 'squinnier', 'squinnies', 'squinny', 'squoosh']
t: ['tchotchke']; 
u: ['ufologies', 'ufologist', 'ufology', 'uhlan', 'uintahite', 'uxorial', 'uxoricide']
v: ['vying']
w: ['wrack', 'wrang', 'wrassle', 'wrassling', 'wrastle', 'wrastling', 'wrath', 'wreak', 'wreck', 'wrest', 'wrick', 'wried', 'wrier', 'wries', 'wriggle', 'wrigglier', 'wriggling', 'wriggly', 'wring', 'wrinkle', 'wrinklier', 'wrinkling', 'wrinkly', 'wrist', 'wrong', 'wrote', 'wroth', 'wrought', 'wrung', 'wryer', 'wryly', 'wryneck', 'wryness']
x: ['xanthan', 'xanthic', 'xanthin', 'xanthophyll', 'xebec', 'xenia', 'xenic', 'xenodiagnoses', 'xenodiagnosis', 'xenograft', 'xenon', 'xenophile', 'xenophobe', 'xerarch', 'xeric', 'xerographic', 'xerophile', 'xerophilies', 'xerophilous', 'xerophily', 'xerophthalmia', 'xerophthalmic', 'xerophyte', 'xerophytism', 'xeroradiographies', 'xeroradiography', 'xeroses', 'xerosis', 'xerothermic', 'xerotic', 'xerox', 'xerus', 'xiphisterna', 'xiphoid']
y:  ['ycleped', 'yperite', 'ytterbium', 'yttrium']
z: ['zlote', 'zloties', 'zloty', 'zucchetto']
```

Comment: With which word list is this?

Comment: I don't know.  I made it 10 years ago.  Probably a very large one.  Maybe `enable.txt?`

Comment: Anyway you can rerun it with the OWL4?